# Creating a trigger which could not be disabled in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

It is possible to create an trigger (with DBO) on a table which could not be disabled (even by DBO or the sa user)?

I need this trigger for licensing/permission purposes on a piece of software which is deployed on the SQL Server of clients. The problem occurs when the clients try to use an old version of my software and disable the triggers I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, if this happens there is deadlock condition, so all software don't want this.

Also it will make system prone to hackers, so you need to understand that this is not possible , sa user or Admin can everytime update rights.

You need to think some other approach like saving licensing in encrypted form, or some code around to fix up such kind of issues